# Why can't I access my ODBC dBase table?

Tags: c#, odbc, dbase

I inherited some C# code. It handles old dBase files. Nobody touched the code for at least 3-5 years, and a compiled version works somewhere out there, but I don't have access to it. Now that I try how it works by recompiling it from source on the same looking environment where it is supposed to run (same architecture, sufficient looking drivers), it gives me the following error:

```
[42S02] [Microsoft][ODBC dBase driver] A Microsoft Jet database engine could not find the object 'test'. Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly.
```

(*EDIT*) on the second line of

```
dbCommand.CommandText = "SELECT Count(*) FROM test";
recNum = (int)dbCommand.ExecuteScalar();
```

(*EDIT*) with the connection string

```
OdbcConnection connection = new OdbcConnection(String.Format("driver={{Microsoft dBase Driver (*.dbf)}};DriverID=533;Dbq={0};Exclusive=1;", path));
```

I tried the obvious solutions found on Google, like making sure if the file is actually there, changing the file name, etc. So, I'm pretty sure that the file is where it is supposed to be, I'm pretty sure that the file isn't damaged (I can open it with some shareware I downloaded from the internet, not to mention that the file didn't change in the last 3-5 years either). This is my first time with dBase and ODBC so I might just miss something that should be obvious.

What else could I try to make it work?

Comment: You could provide the code at the line where it fails?

Comment: I noticed issues when I used the C# code on a x64 machine. In my case, I changed the target output to x86 and worked. But meanwhile, I also had to check the dBase driver existence on machine. Which was the most painful part! But, luckily, I had access to the production version of installer which installs all required drivers and things worked after the installation!

Comment: edit added. the architecture is the same as before (x86), the dBase driver is supposedly the same. or I don't know how could I tell if there is a difference. sadly the production version installer doesn't install any drivers.

Comment: The "could not find the object" error has the name of the object just where you've put the ellipsis...

Comment: At least get rid of the extra space after "test".  Does this dbase really contain a table named "test"?

Comment: done. nothing changed, as expected. if it means that the database path contains a `test.dbf` file then yes, it contains the table. otherwise I didn't get the most basic concept I guess.

Comment: Baffling. What connection string are you using? You could try ProcessMonitor to see what files it actually tries to open.

Comment: it tries to open two files: `C:\Documents and Settings\ytg\Local Settings\Temp\JETCD65.tmp` and `C:\Documents and Settings\ytg\Local Settings\Temp\JETCC3C.tmp`. I guess they are created by ODBC.

Comment: That all works for me. Could it be a VFP table? There's a separate driver ID on my machine for FoxPro, although I don't have it installed.

Comment: Very unlikely. It's all inherited, I didn't change anything yet.

Comment: @ytg I guess it succeeds with both those files? Interestingly it doesn't even look at the DBF file which suggests that your path is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you have configured an ODBC data source (Start > Settings > Control Panel > ODBC). 
The name of the data source must be included in the connection string for your Connection object.
The table test must be a table of the database to which the configured data source points.

Comment: This looked promising until I set a file DSN on the directory. Maybe I do something very wrong, but it just created a `.dsn` file in the directory. Which is kind of suspicious because if it is all about that, the file should be there already. Not to mention that it doesn't seem to point to database tables at all. (Only to the directory.) I'm using XP if that matters.

Comment: The dsn file is just a file that contains the parameters of the ODBC configuration. I would prefer to create a User DSN. Click Add, choose dBase File and the dBase ODBC driver you want to use and enter the configuration parameters. In your application you must then refer to that data source in the connection string.

Comment: With this it just still doesn't work. There wasn't any data source in the original connection string anyway, so it might have handled the thing in an other way. (Connection string added to the original question.)

Comment: So what value does path have? It should contain a directory name that has a file named test.dbf in it.

Comment: You could also try setting DriverId set to 277 for dBase IV. 533 is dBase V.

Comment: that's the directory. and I think I have dBase V (I'll check tomorrow)

Answer (score 0):

So many people like to use Jet on older .dbf files, yet they may not in fact be dBASE, but actually Foxpro (slightly different header info).  You may actually need to download and work with the VFP OleDB provider.

I've [answered previous questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8536258/cant-access-dbf-file-if-other-app-is-accessing-it/8538655#8538655) that help show / describe connections, in addition, a link to Microsoft to get / download the latest Visual Foxpro OleDB provider.

Just a note on the connection string.  Even if the .dbf file is NOT part of a "database", but a free table, you would want to connect to the physical PATH where the data resides, THEN just query based on the name of the table to get your data.